# Rest API create personal site enque

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, my-site, jsom

I'm trying to provision My Site by utilizing SharePoint JSOM or REST API.
The JSOM code snippet (below) gives `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` and REST call gives me a 401.
The goal here is to provision My Site for users in the background without them  actually visiting their personal page.
Any ideas on why this does not work?

**JSOM**

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var loader = SP.UserProfiles.ProfileLoader.getProfileLoader(clientContext);
clientContext.load(loader)
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
profile = loader.getUserProfile();
clientContext.load(profile);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
       profile.createPersonalSiteEnque(false);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
          function () { console.log("OK") }, 
          function (a, b) { console.log(a); console.log(b); });
       },
       function (a, b) { console.log(a); console.log(b); });
},
function (a, b) { console.log(a); console.log(b); });
```

**REST**

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: Constants.Site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.profileloader.getprofileloader/getuserprofile/createpersonalsiteenque(true)",
      headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": formDigestValue
                            }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });
```

Comment: Where are you running this from? An app? A web page? Console app?

Comment: **wjervis**: The code will run on a page residing in the root catalog of the SharePoint site.